# Unintended Numbering of Theorems

Tags: theorems

It is difficult for me to put a good MWE as I do not know what supporting packages are. Anyway, below are the code:

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{report}
 \usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{indentfirst,tasks,enumitem,mathpazo,multicol,booktabs,mathcmd,cancel,array,tabularx,fancybox,ascmac,bigstrut,etoolbox,stmaryrd,xspace,skak,ragged2e,pmboxdraw,bbding,enumitem,array,fontspec,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools,tikz,graphicx,fancyhdr,geometry,tabulary,tabularx}

 \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
    \usepackage{environ}
    \newtheorem*{answer}{\doublebox{{\scriptsize Answer:}}}
    \mdfdefinestyle{ans}{
      linecolor=black,
  %backgroundcolor=gray!20
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=ans]{answer}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\NewEnviron{rotan}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[rotate=180,inner sep=0pt] {\parbox{\linewidth}{
  \begin{answer}
  \BODY
 \end{answer}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{rotan}
\begin{enumerate*}
\item
\begin{enumerate*}
\item y=0...\end{enumerate*}
\end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

I want remove the numbering of Answer, so I tried adding * but it does not work. 
[image]

After Answer, there is still one DOT left.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, at least make suture that the code you post is enough for others to compile it. This is not as there is no preamble or document class listed.

Comment: do you use `amsthm` or `ntheorem` packages?

Comment: I use     amsthm . Documentclass is report...

Comment: Do you really need:   (i) all those packages in your preamble and (ii) many of them to load twice? Please, remove all unnecesariness in your MWE.

Comment: @Zarko I am at the stage of trying different methods to write a book. Sometimes I add packages twice because I do not remember what I added before. Since Latex does not mind that, I keep them like it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, if the following is what you looking for:

[image]

Above picture is obtained by:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
    \usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
    \usepackage{calc,graphicx}
    \usepackage[margin=25mm,showframe]{geometry}

\makeatletter
    \newsavebox\answerbox
\newenvironment{rotansw}%
    {\@parboxrestore%
     \begin{lrbox}{\answerbox}%
     \begin{minipage}{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
     \fbox{\fbox{\textbf{Answers}}}\quad~
    }{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}
      \rotatebox{180}{\framebox{\usebox{\answerbox}}}%
     }
\makeatother

    \begin{document}
\begin{rotansw}
\begin{enumerate*}[label=\textbf{(\alph*)},itemsep=2em]
\item y=0...
\item x=0...
\item z=0...
\item y=0...
\item x=0...
\item z=0...
\item y=0...
\item x=0...
\item z=0...
    \end{enumerate*}
\end{rotansw}

\begin{rotansw}
Answer on single question. It can include graphics
    \begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\hsize]{example-image}
    \end{center}
as part of answer explanation.
\end{rotansw}
    \end{document}
```

As you can see, I take different approach for define environment for answers as you. I estimate that for it is not necessary to use `amsthm`.

With option `showframe` in package `geometry` I just show, that answer is is fit into text width. In real use, this option should be omitted.

**Addendum:** Since with recent MikTeX I can not tested your MWE (it seems, that packages as `animate`, `mdframe`, `tcolorbox` etc are broken :-( ), I only suspect, what is going wrong with your solution for answer. The number is left from outer enumerate. It can be eliminated with:

- with use of `\item[]`
- not use outer `enumerate`

Anyway, above suggested, solution gives similar result as you show in question, however for it is required only package `calc` (for calculation of mini page width), package `enumitem` is used only for inline enumerate of answers.

Comment: @Panha, see, if my answer and addendum in it solve your problem

Comment: It is mdframed, not mdframe. I am using it regularly though. I use it as it can span across pages. However, this rotatbox does not span. I am not sure if your example spans across pages but it solves my problem for the moment. Thanks alot.

Comment: My solution contain `minipage` which can not be break over more pages. The same is valid for `rotatebox`.  Unfortunately.